# Behavior on clustered environment

Tags: marklogic

In clustered environment, I guess basically load balancer will pass request to one of E-nodes.
Now, how does each E-node understands which D-nodes to access when particular query is executed?
I am bit confused with how the index and cache works under clustered environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain the distinction between E- and D-nodes first.

Any host that participates in a MarkLogic cluster can potentially operate as E or D, or even both.

Whether a host operates as E-node is determined by the fact whether it is in a group with app-servers that are relevant to you, like one that exposes some REST api that you need. So, not just Admin or App-Services, but usually something more specific.

Whether a host operates as D-node is determined by the fact whether it holds any forests of a database that is relevant to you, like one that holds part or all data used by a relevant app-server. So not just Modules or Documents, but usually something more specific.

All hosts in a cluster have a complete copy of the cluster config. MarkLogic will take care of getting data when one host needs data located in a forest on a different host.

So, D-nodes are related to data-storage, and that includes indexes, both on disk and in memory.

E-nodes are used to 'evaluate' incoming requests, hence the 'E'. Some caching happens on D-nodes, but expanded tree caches and such typically reside on E-node, so that they don't need to access other hosts to fetch data.

You normally don't need to worry too much about all this, until you reach a stage where you need to tweak performance, which can be very case specific. It can be useful to ask MarkLogic to help with that, if you are in a position to do so.

Now, with regard to load balancing, that only concerns incoming requests, so is relevant to E-nodes. If all hosts are in one Group (not uncommon), every host can act as E-node. The load balancer will need to know the network IPs or names of those machines to relay traffic. In a virtualized environment you probably want to take it even a step further, and allow automatic scaling up and down. The [MarkLogic Query Service](https://www.marklogic.com/product/marklogic-database-overview/query-service/) is also relevant to this.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for your great answer, how about when data is inserted, how and when does each node synchronize data/index?

Comment: There is no synchronization of data nor indexes, only caching. The fact that each host is responsible for the forests it owns allows a high degree of parallelization, which is why MarkLogic can give fast (sub-second) answers even in large clusters.

Comment: Thanks again, I see.. great shared-nothing technology. Is there any doc explains about cache synchronization flow?

Comment: I'm not sure how detailed that particular bit has been described anywhere, but for a deep understanding of MarkLogic in broad sense, I highly recommend reading the [Inside MarkLogic Server](https://www.marklogic.com/resources/inside-marklogic-server/) whitepaper.